# Can a vector space, A, which is subset of another vector space , B, is not a subspace over that another vector space, B?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to self-study linear algebra so I have no people to refer to face-to-face. Sorry if this is a basic question. The question comes from a book I'm using. The question is a true or false question.
( If V is a vector space and W is a subset of V that is a vector space,
then W is a subspace of V.) I then look for a solution online and it says ( No. This should make sure that the field and the operations of V and
W are the same. Otherwise for example, V = *R* and W = *Q* respectly.
Then W is a vector space over *Q* but not a space over *R* and so not
a subspace of V )
From what I understand, the statement 'W is a subset of V that is a vector space' means that W is a vector space and should pass the condition for the subspace. Which means the answer should be true.
Or did I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\;\Bbb Q\;$ of all rational numbers is a vector space over itself (meaning, you can use only rational scalars), and this set is a subset of the vector space $\;\Bbb R\;$ of the real numbers over itself, yet the former is not a subspace of the latter since these two vector spaces aren't defined over the very same field .

Very important: a set $\;A\;$ is a vector (or linear) subspace of space $\;B\;$ iff (1) $\;A\subset B\;$ (subset) **and also** (2) if both these vector spaces are defined over the very same field of scalars.

Comment: Your conditions (1) and (2) are necessary but not sufficient. The operations on $A$ (the zero vector can be considered a $0$-ary operation) need to be the restrictions of the corresponding operations on $B$, not other operations which also happen to make $A$ into a vector space over the same field but not a subspace.